# Which RAID levels and related are supported by bcachefs and how to configure?

Tags: filesystems, raid, software-raid, bcachefs

**2023-10-31, Bcachefs Merged Into The Linux 6.7 Kernel:**

- https://www.phoronix.com/news/Bcachefs-Merged-Linux-6.7
- https://web.archive.org/web/20231103095158/https://www.phoronix.com/news/Bcachefs-Merged-Linux-6.7

How can I configure and use the different RAID levels supported by the filesystem bcachefs via software RAID?

This question is about software RAID modes that bcachefs supports. Modes that are comparable to the requirements of classic RAID levels are referred to as RAID as a working term, regardless of the fact that they may have other names in bcachefs.

And which DUP or comparable RAID modes does bcachefs also support? Possible they are syntax like the follow:

```
--replicas=n # perhaps, n can be replaced by 2 and other counts
```

Answer (score 0):

Bcachefs supports as software RAID among other things with the following classical RAID variants approximately comparable RAID variants: RAID 0, 1, 5, 6, and 10.

However, there are differences in the implementation, so that, for example, the [write hole](https://enwp.org/write_hole) problem that occurs in different RAID implementations of RAID 5 and 6 is avoided.

You can create the different levels of filesystem on follow way:

RAID0 striping:

```
mkfs.bcachefs -a raid0 /dev/sda /dev/sdb
```

RAID 1 mirroring:

```
mkfs.bcachefs -a raid1 /dev/sda /dev/sdb
```

RAID5:

```
mkfs.bcachefs -a raid5 /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc
```

RAID6:

```
mkfs.bcachefs -a raid6 /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd
```

RAID 10:

```
mkfs.bcachefs -a raid10 /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd
```

Comment: How about "DUP" modes? Possible thats called by bcachefs "--replicas=2" or so on. But I didnt find good sample codes on this time for this.

Comment: It was pointed out in a flag comment that the `bcachefs format` command (which is the same as `mkfs.bcachefs` command) does not have the options showed in this answer.